# WCF application Endpoint not found

Tags: wcf

So the problem I could guess I'm facing is the configuration of web config. Let me tell what I'm doing,

1. Created WCF library
2. created on WCF application and refer the library DLL.

After that when I run the WCF application it gives me the error endpoint not found.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.CardService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="HostBehavior">
        <endpoint 
            address="" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CardCustomBinding" 
            contract="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.ICardService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CardCustomBinding" allowCookies="true" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000"  
                        maxArrayLength="20000000"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HostBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I just want to test it on my local machine not on the server. I am adding my WCF library config part as well that might also help in sorting out the issue.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior" name="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.CardService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.ICardService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/service/1.0/rest" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: How are you **hosting** this service? Using a `*.svc` file inside of IIS? Please show us the `*.svc` file! Or using a self-hosting mechanism? Please show us how you spin up the `WebServiceHost`

Comment: Below is what the meta data of SVC file. <%@ ServiceHost Service="Boost.Web.CARD.services.CardServiceLibrary.CardService"    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %> Fow now I'm not using the IIS for hosting just F5 the project to test how WCF application return the library functions.

Comment: Do I need to provide anything else which will help in sorting out the issue.